# mysql Select Like column like column1 OR column2

Tags: c#, mysql

In my webapp, I have a search box so that I can search my database using the firstname or lastname and it will display the result in my web app.User input the firstname or lastname.Use Like query..how to write Like query in this query.

```
 public DataTable SearchbyOPDname(string fname, string lname)
   {
       if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
           con.Open();
       }
       string sql = "SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No], opd_date AS DATE, opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT, 
       opd_pfname AS [FIRST NAME], opd_plname AS [LAST NAME], opd_age AS AGE, opd_gender AS GENDER, 
       opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO], opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME], opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME] 
       FROM tbl_OPD WHERE opd_pfname like'" + fname +"' OR opd_plname like'" + lname + "'ORDER BY DATE DESC";
       SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       adp.Fill(dt);
       con.Close();
       return dt;
   }
```

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: Use always [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of codes is open for [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: i think syntax of LIKE is wrong in this query

Comment: Put percentage signs % around the values you are applying the LIKE clasue to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use LIKE to do partial matching you have to include the `%` sign before and after the pattern. This should work just fine:

```
string sql = @"SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No]
              , opd_date AS DATE
              , opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT
              , opd_pfname AS [FIRST NAME]
              , opd_plname AS [LAST NAME]
              , opd_age AS AGE
              , opd_gender AS GENDER
              , opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO]
              , opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME]
              , opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME] 
          FROM tbl_OPD 
         WHERE opd_pfname LIKE '%" + fname + @"%'
            OR opd_plname LIKE '%" + lname + @"%'
         ORDER BY DATE DESC";
```

As a side note, you should use parameterized queries instead of manually constructing your query like that!

Here's how to do the same with a paramterized query:

```
  using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
  {
     cmd.Text = @"SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No]
              , opd_date AS DATE
              , opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT
              , opd_pfname AS [FIRST NAME]
              , opd_plname AS [LAST NAME]
              , opd_age AS AGE
              , opd_gender AS GENDER
              , opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO]
              , opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME]
              , opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME] 
          FROM tbl_OPD 
         WHERE opd_pfname LIKE '%' + @fname + '%'
            OR opd_plname LIKE '%' + @lname + '%'
         ORDER BY DATE DESC"

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@fname, fname);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@lname, lname);

     cmd.Prepare();

     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     adp.Fill(dt);
  }
   con.Close();
```

Comment: Thankyou so much sir for help me to find the solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `%` for your `LIKE` part;

```
WHERE opd_pfname LIKE '%" + fname + @"%' OR opd_plname LIKE '%" + lname + @"%'
```

- [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

But more important is (as I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502523/mysql-select-like-column-like-column1-or-column2#comment21950132_15502523)) always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. Your code is open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks. For example;

```
         WHERE opd_pfname LIKE '%' + @fname + '%'
            OR opd_plname LIKE '%' + @lname + '%'

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@fname, fname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@lname, lname);

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
```